# Android resource version crash error

Tags: android, resources

Resource error

[image]

When I made moudle it's default compile SDK VERSION was 28 and TARGET SDK WAS 28

but, I want to downgrade to 26 because of annoing appcompat library error so I go SDK MANAGER and delete api 28 and set SDK VERSION 26, TARGET SDK 26 then this error in image occured How can i fix it? one more When i try to make module it's default compile sdk version is always 28 so I want configure it to 26

Comment: Have you tried  `Invalidate Caches / Restart` ?

Comment: after Ivalidate Caches / Restart some of moddules not working propertly and

Comment: org.gradle.initialization.ReportedException: org.gradle.internal.exceptions.LocationAwareException: Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.

Comment: I finally reproduced your error. May see your `gradle` app level?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3` version that is higher than `compileSdkVersion`. To fix this you just have to match or increase the `compileSdkVersion` to `28`, or lower your `com.android.support:appcompat` version.